# how to stream with mule sftp connector

Tags: mule

We have a soap service that accepts a small file so we receive that in memory and we need to then sftp that off to another server.  What would the configuration be for that?  How to take our String(xml file) and send it to the server?  ( i assume sftp connector is the best way to go here, but how to configure it as it looks like it takes one file as a parameter and I need it to be fed bytes to send instead with a filename that we specify).

thanks,
Dean

Comment: I don't get it. Do you or don't you receive the XML file content over the inbound SOAP service?

Comment: we receive xml over the soap service and can translate that to bytes(it's a JAXB object to be more specific once we get it in our component).  How do I then sftp the file to the server without putting it on the local disk?

Comment: When you say "How do I then sftp the file", what file are you talking about? Do you mean the bytes[] representation of the JAXB object?